# How does one build a custom Bootstrap WebJar with sbt?

Tags: sbt, webjars

I want to build a WebJar that contains a brand-customized version of Bootstrap from LESS source. I have `sbt.version=0.13.5-M4` in `project/build.properties` and `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0-M2a")` in `project/plugins.sbt`. My `build.sbt` looks like this:

```
import com.typesafe.web.sbt.WebPlugin
import com.typesafe.jse.sbt.JsEnginePlugin
import com.typesafe.web.sbt.WebPlugin.WebKeys

name := "brand-assets"

organization := "com.example"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

WebPlugin.webSettings

JsEnginePlugin.jsEngineSettings

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).addPlugins(SbtWeb)

excludeFilter in Assets := new PatternFilter("""[^_].*\.less""".r.pattern)
```

The errors I get are:

```
build.sbt:1: error: object web is not a member of package com.typesafe
import com.typesafe.web.sbt.WebPlugin
                    ^
build.sbt:2: error: object sbt is not a member of package com.typesafe.jse
import com.typesafe.jse.sbt.JsEnginePlugin
                        ^
build.sbt:15: error: value addPlugins is not a member of sbt.Project
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).addPlugins(SbtWeb)
                                       ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

So far i unserstand your question, you should add the following line to `plugin.sbt`:

```
resolvers += Resolver.typesafeRepo("releases")
```

as disused at https://github.com/sbt/sbt-less/issues/31